# jQuery echo a statement in a textbox if a value is greater than another

Tags: jquery, if-statement, echo

I have a code that calculates the mileage from both point A and point B. If the mileage is less than 75 miles away from either point A OR point B, I want to return "FREE" however, if it is more than 75 miles away from both I want to return the statement "You will be charged expenses".

I thought I could handle this with simple if, else if and else statements, but it's not working at all:

```
function initialize() {
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
}
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsService2 = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function calcRoute() {
var distance1Input = document.getElementById("distance1");
var MileageInput = document.getElementById("mileage");
var start = "DE75 7AH";

var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
var request = {
origin:start,
destination:end,
travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
distance1Input.value = Math.round(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1609.344);
    } 
});

//second route
var distance2Input = document.getElementById("distance2");
var start2 = "AL8 6RE";

var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
var request2 = {
origin:start2,
destination:end,
travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
};

directionsService2.route(request2, function(response, status) {
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
distance2Input.value = Math.round(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1609.344);
    } 
});

//mileage cost
var mileageCost = Math.round(((response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1609.344)-75)+100);

var derbyDistance = distance1Input.value;
var londonDistance = distance2Input.value;

if (derbyDistance < 75) {
MileageInput.value = 'FREE';
}
else if (londonDistance < 75) {
MileageInput.value = 'FREE';
}
else {
MileageInput.value = 'You will be charged expenses';
}

}
```

The part of the code in question is at the bottom where I am trying to return statements based on how far away the end point is.

You can see this script in action here:
http://www.samskirrow.com/projects/distr_maps/index2.html

Thanks for the help

Comment: You're not using jQuery.

Comment: Line 54 : you reference the `response` variable, which is only known inside the `directionsService2.route(request2, function(response, status)` function. You need to put that code in there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

response is unknown outside of the `.route` method calls. You should pass it, this way :

```
function initialize() {
 directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
}

var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsService2 = new google.maps.DirectionsService();


function calcRoute() {
  var distance1Input = document.getElementById("distance1");
  var MileageInput = document.getElementById("mileage");

  var start = "DE75 7AH";
  var end = document.getElementById("end").value;

  var request = {
  origin:start,
  destination:end,
  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  distance1Input.value = Math.round(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1609.344);
  displayExpenses(response);
          } 
      });

  //second route
  var distance2Input = document.getElementById("distance2");
  var start2 = "AL8 6RE";

  var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
  var request2 = {
  origin:start2,
  destination:end,
  travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };

  directionsService2.route(request2, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  distance2Input.value = Math.round(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1609.344);
  displayExpenses(response);
          } 
      });

  function displayExpenses(response){
    var mileageCost = Math.round(((response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1609.344)-75)+100);

    var derbyDistance = distance1Input.value;
    var londonDistance = distance2Input.value;

    if (derbyDistance < 75) {
      MileageInput.value = 'FREE';
    }
    else if (londonDistance < 75) {
      MileageInput.value = 'FREE';
    }
    else {
        MileageInput.value = 'You will be charged expenses';
    }
  }   
}
```

[**WorkingFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RrVm3/)

Answer (score 1):

Since your calculations seem to work right and the text inputs seem to be updated correctly, I think this might be a problem in the last `if` statement. You are comparing an integer (`75`) to the `value` of a text input which is a `string`.

Try using [`parseInt()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) to avoid these problems:

```
if (parseInt(derbyDistance) < 75) {
  MileageInput.value = 'FREE';
}
else if (parseInt(londonDistance) < 75) {
  MileageInput.value = 'FREE';
}
else {
  MileageInput.value = 'You will be charged expenses';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var mileageCost = Math.round(((response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1609.344)-75)+100);
```

In the browser console, Am getting `response is undefined` error.

Because

```
directionsService2.route(request2, function(response, status) {
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
distance2Input.value = Math.round(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1609.344);
        } 
    });

//mileage cost
var mileageCost = Math.round(((response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1609.344)-75)+100);
```

you are trying to access response outside the route() function